# Probability of choosing the correct missing digit > 0.5?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The question goes as follows:

> A person has forgotten the last digit of a telephone number, so he dials
>   the number with the last digit randomly chosen. How many times does he have to dial
>   (not counting repetitions) in order that the probability of dialing the correct number
>   is more than 0.5.

The way I answered it was in the following format:

Denote try 1 success as $T_1$, and subsequently follows:

$ P(T_1 \cup (T_2 \cap T_1^c) \cup (T_3 \cap T_2^c \cap T_1^c)  ...) \gt 0.5 $

We know the union of these events can be expressed as additions because they're disjoint, so:

$ P(T_1) + ... P(T_n \cap T_{n-1}^c ... T_1^c) \gt 0.5$

We also know that in each, the event of $T_x$ and $T_y$ such that $x \ne y$ is independent. Then we can say for $P(T_n \cap T_{n-1}^c ... T_1^c)$ for example it becomes:

$P(T_n) P(T_{n-1}^c) ... P(T_1^c)$

So I just kept calculating the probabilities, which are 1/10, 1/9, 1/8, 1/7... 1 for the $T_n$'s and 9/10, 8/9, 7/8, 6/7... for the $T_n^c$'s. Iteratively doing this I found an answer.

However, this is pretty tedious. I was wondering if there was a closed form solution, or **if this is even correct?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct: if he makes $5$ attempts, the chance that he gets the correct number is the chance that he gets it on the first try $+$ the chance he gets it wrong on the first try and right on the second try, and so on up to the chance that he gets it wrong the first $4$ tries and right on the fifth try.

Here's an intuitive understanding: he'll go through all $10$ digits possible if he needs to. The correct digit is just as likely to be in the first $5$ digits he tries as it is to be in the last $5$ digits he tries, so it's a $\frac{1}{2}$ chance with $5$ tries. Thus, $6$ tries will make it more likely, which will push the probability over $.5$.

Comment: Thank you! It totally makes intuitive sense, but as I have experienced, intuition doesn't always pull through on probability proofs. So thank you for reassuring me that I'm not crazy :)